# Rails chartkick how to add names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, ruby-on-rails-5, chartkick, diagrams

I am using gem 'chartkick' and have such code:

```
        <%= pie_chart question.responses.group(:answer_variant_id).count %>
```

the table `responses` is connected with table `answer_variants` through `answer_variant_id`. Currently my pie chart shows answer variant ids, but how could I make it displaying answer_variant.title?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this. Needed to join another table. The answer looks like this:

```
<%= pie_chart question.responses.joins(:answer_variant).group(:title).count %>
```